# How to get "sum" of true bools

Tags: go, sum, boolean, boolean-operations

In this scenario I have 3x boolean vars (already set to either `true` or `false`)

**The goal here is to identify if more than one of the set of bool vars are set to true**

Right now I have the following written, which does work:

```
    boolval := 0
    if *firstbool {
        boolval++
    }
    if *secondbool {
        boolval++
    }
    if *thirdbool {
        boolval++
    }
    if boolval > 1 {
        // More than 1 of the bool vars are true
    }
```

I always flag my logic if I am writing successive `if{}` statements, so I figured I would ask you geniuses how you would accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> identify if more than one of the set of bool vars are set to true

---

For example, write a set function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func nTrue(b ...bool) int {
    n := 0
    for _, v := range b {
        if v {
            n++
        }
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    v1, v2, v3 := true, false, true

    fmt.Println(nTrue(v1, v2, v3))

    if nTrue(v1, v2, v3) > 1 {
        // . .   .
    }
    // Or
    if n := nTrue(v1, v2, v3); n > 1 {
        // . .   .
    }
    // Or
    n := nTrue(v1, v2, v3)
    if n > 1 {
        // . .   .
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/g3WCN6BgGly

Output:

```
2
```

---

For example, range over the set,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    v1, v2, v3 := true, false, true

    boolval := 0
    for _, v := range []bool{v1, v2, v3} {
        if v {
            boolval++
        }
    }
    if boolval > 1 {
        // . .   .
    }

    fmt.Println(boolval > 1, boolval)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/R6UGb8YYEFw

Output:

```
true 2
```

Comment: Is there really no better way to say "count the number of elements equal to `x`"?

Comment: @Alexander Go is notorious for leaving the low level but straightforward operations to the implementer. The language's opinion is that doing otherwise is hiding the true complexity of those operations.

Comment: @AdamSmith Interesting. Not my cup of tea, but I haven't looked too deeply into why that is or what advantages it might have

Comment: @Alexander I choose it because it is incredibly simple and straightforward to compile standalone linux, win, and mac executables. Typically I go with python but the cross-platform functionality & natural portability of Go really hooked me.

Comment: @emmdee Yeah, I've heard of those "perks",  just the "use primitives for most things" style is novel to me

Answer (score -3):

Depending on how you're getting the values of `firstbool` et. al, there might be a more idiomatic approach you should take here. Consider that channels and goroutines can handle doing the accounting in the background. If your booleans are the result of some heavier operations, it might make sense to do something like:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func firstFunc(ch chan bool) {
    // assume this works, true!
    ch <- true
}

func secondFunc(ch chan bool) {
    // assume this fails, false!
    ch <- false
}

func thirdFunc(ch chan bool) {
    // assume this works, true!
    ch <- true
}

func listener(ch chan bool, numCallers int) <-chan bool {
    outch := make(chan bool)
    THRESHOLD := 2
    go func(outch chan<- bool) {
        count := 0
        trues := 0

        for count < numCallers && trues < THRESHOLD {
            val := <-ch
            if val {
                trues++
            }
            count++
        }
        outch <- trues >= THRESHOLD
    }(outch)
    return outch
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    resultch := listener(ch, 3)

    go firstFunc(ch)
    go secondFunc(ch)
    go thirdFunc(ch)

    if <-resultch {
        fmt.Println("Two or more processes succeeded")
    }
}
```

However this is *way* over-engineered for a simple need, so consider this only if this pattern fits the larger design of your application.